# storing javascript code with a function in database

Tags: javascript, php, sql, store

i tried many times to store the following js code,but it was broken and db didn't store it completely,although when i tried to store a js code that don't have function,or any other code like a php code...java code ,it was stored normally

i used mysqli_real_escape_string,prepare stmt,htmlentities...........and all methods,but nothing happened

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function youtubeFeedCallback(json){
        document.write('<img src="' + json.data.thumbnail.sqDefault + '">');
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/gzDS-Kfd5XQ?v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=youtubeFeedCallback"></script>
```

the code is stored in db as like that:

```
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;<br />
    function youtubeFeedCallback(json){<br />
        document.write('&lt;img src=&quot;'   json.data.thumbnail.sqDefault   '&quot;&gt;');<br />
    }<br />
&lt;/script&gt;<br />
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot; src=&quot;http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/gzDS-Kfd5XQ?v=2
```

js code that add data using ajax function

```
$(document).ready(function(){





$("#submit").click(function() {

    var ans_body = escape($("#ans_body").val());
    var q_id = $("#q_id").val();
    var dataString = 'ans_body=' + ans_body + '&q_id=' + q_id;

    if(ans_body=='')
     {
    alert('برجاء كتابة الاجابة صحيحة');
     }
    else
    {
    $("#flash").show();
    $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;<span class="loading">Loading answers...</span>');
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "includes/submit_comment.php",
  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
   data: dataString,

  cache: false,
  success: function(html){

  $("ol#update").append(html);
  $("ol#update li:last").fadeIn("slow");
    document.getElementById('ans_body').value='';
    $("#ans_body").focus();

  $("#flash").hide();

  }
 });
}
return false;
    });





    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it

the problem is in the ajax function that need to escape special characters as html code before sending request
so to solve this 
use escape function when u send data using ajax function

```
var ans_body = escape($("#ans_body").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code is cut off, is the DB field long enough to store the whole function? As for the `&lt;` `&gt;`, `&quot`, and `<br />` things, those are just html entities, when you extract the function, you can switch them out for their code equivalents (<, >, ", line break)

Comment: i store the code in (text) field and it's enough,and i used htmlentities as i mentioned......any other ideas?!!!!

Comment: so, the code you try to insert into the db is the first one? and you use htmlentites on it before inserting?